# APPPATH codeigniter doesnt work on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem in codeigniter - after I upload it to the server I am requiring a file in a model from libraries folder

```
<?php
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/MY_Model.php');
Class scroll_news_model extends MY_model
{
 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct("scroll_news");
 }
}
```

this code was working fine in my localhost environment but I keep getting this error after I upload it:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'application/libraries/MY_Model.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/arab2day/public_html/temp/arab2day/application/models/scroll_news_model.php on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to extend the `CI_Model` class, `MY_Model.php` belongs in the `/core` directory rather than `/libraries`, and you don't need to include it - it will be loaded automatically when the base model class is loaded.

This is how extending core classes works, extending regular non-essential "libraries" is slightly different. Read more about it here:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

As far as the literal problem goes, [Lepidosteus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9242831/398242) makes a good point about case sensitivity and OS, I've run into this issue myself several times.

Answer (score 8):

Check the case of your file names; windows makes no difference between `ABC.php` and `abc.php`, but linux does.

Comment: No problem, please press the "validate answer" button on the left if this answered your question

Comment: @RamySelim: This is not how you extend the model class in Codeigniter, you're loading the file unnecessarily. Also, CI normalizes file names to an extent if you use the loader class rather than `include`.

Comment: Wow, the same discrepancy occurs between **MacOS** and Linux. I was totally ready to discount this answer until I looked closely at the string I was passing to require_once(), and indeed, its capitalization didn't match that of my target file. I had expected that MacOS, being based on BSD, wouldn't do such silly stuff -- but then, Apple has been fiddling it for years to be more "friendly" (yeah right). Apparently this is a feature of HFS+. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22304/37410

Comment: @Hephaestus I would argue that the windows way or treating them as the same, while more user friendly, is wrong, especially when viewed from a programming point of view. "a" and "A" are two very different characters, and you only need to think about the same issue with non-latin alphabet to see why this is a terrible idea. So the unix way (found in linux, bsd, osx, ...) is the "right" way: if you ask for something don't give something else that might be the same, maybe, we hope ...

Comment: @Lepidosteus Yes, it's precisely that wrongness of the HFS+ approach that got me and the OP in trouble, and which I've since seen trip others up, in other contexts. (Perhaps you didn't notice my double-quoting of the term "friendly" ;-)