# Codeigniter: Unable to locate the specified class: Exceptions.php

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

Here's my controller:

```
$html = $this->load->view('print_po', $po, TRUE);
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
```

Now I've tried and comment each line and the one that shows the error is:

```
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
```

Here's my library class in **application/libraries**:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class pdf {

    function pdf()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');
    }

    function load($param=NULL)
    {
        include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

        if ($params == NULL)
        {
            $param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3';
        }

        return new mPDF($param);
    }
}
```

The error comes only after moving the code from one server to another(the error happens on a CentOS server which I bet is case sensitive). My question here would be: what should I modify so codeIgniter loads Exceptions.php normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** remove the forward-slash at the first of `/third_party` phrase:

```
include_once APPPATH.'third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';
```

CodeIgniter defines `APPPATH` constant with a trailing slash. Take a look at `index.php`:

```
define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
```

**Second,** make sure that the file/folder names are as the same as you have wrote. <s>It's better to keep them all lowercase.</s> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242788/apppath-codeigniter-doesnt-work-on-server) is a related topic.

**Update:**

The class name should be Capitalized. In this case change the `pdf` to `Pdf`:

```
class Pdf {
 // ...
}
```

*[From CI Documentation:](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)*

**Naming Conventions:**

- File names must be capitalized. For example:  `Myclass.php`
- Class declarations must be capitalized. For example:  `class Myclass`
- Class names and file names must match.

Comment: I did what you've suggested but doesn't work. Also, all the files are in lowercase. I think the problem here is with CI and a missing ucfirst() somewhere, maybe?

Comment: The error I get is: **Unable to locate the specified class: Exceptions.php** I checked your update and tried that as well before but still not working. Also, I commented `if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');` and   `$CI = & get_instance();
       log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');`

Comment: Sorry for double posting... So I've found the error is caused by this line: `include_once APPPATH.'third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';` Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: @CristiBerceanu Try to include the file using a path relative to `index.php` file. for example: `include_once './application/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';`. depend on your folder structure.

Comment: I did but still no result. :(

Comment: @CristiBerceanu If the problem is with `include` function, first check if the file exists: `var_dump( file_exists(APPPATH.'third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php') );` let me know the result.

Comment: Tried that as well before, it returns bool(true).

Comment: @CristiBerceanu That's weird... also check whether the file is readable on the server using `var_dump( is_readable(APPPATH.'third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php') );` if it returns `true` the problem is something else.

Comment: @CristiBerceanu So the error should not belongs to `include`, are you sure that the `mpdf` class works without error? make a tiny class instead, include it and do some tests to debug the code. I can't say anything else. something is wrong but it is somewhere else, not the code at the current page.

Comment: Using another class works fine, indeed. My question is... why does mpdf try to load Exceptions.pdf.

Comment: @CristiBerceanu I have not any experience with `mPDF` class, never used before, but if another class works fine, the codes on this page are completely okay. there are many libraries to create pdf file, try another.

Comment: @CristiBerceanu It's better to ask separate question for this issue, but could you consider marking this answer as valid please?