# Class 'REST_Controller' not found with Codeigniter and REST API service

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, api

I'm having a problem with the popular REST API controller maintained by Chris Kacerguis. 
I've imported the three files Format.php, REST_Controller.php and rest.php and placed them in the proper locations in my codeIgniter file structure.
I created a Users controller that looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Users extends REST_Controller{
    public function index_get()
    {
        // Display all users
        $this->response("Get method");
    }
    public function index_post()
    {
        // Create a new user
        $this->response("Post method");
    }
}
?>
```

I keep getting a error message that says: "Class 'REST_Controller' not found" when I navigate to my endpoint: http://localhost/api_test/index.php/users

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: presumably it is finding the file in the `require_once` line, otherwise it would report that it can't find the file (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242788/apppath-codeigniter-doesnt-work-on-server)). Can you verify that the class is in fact defined in that file? Perhaps debug it by adding `print`/`echo` and/or `die` statements in that file to ensure it is reaching that point

Comment: Download latest code from http://www.filetolink.com/a720227fd5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that a new commit was recently made to the library to support namespaces and I believe this is broken as I get the same error. Here is the [problem commit](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/commit/a5ea7ff53710406115a7ba299e1fff3a2a1a41a3).

If you revert those changes, the class will work for you, just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the namespace after require_once and it will work

```
// use namespace
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
```